# Creating dependent dropdown in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I need to create a dependent dropdown in Yii2

I have two tables, `admin` and `employee`, when `admin` selects `employee` name,  `employee's` details such as **email**, **age**, **dateofbirth** and **phone** should get filled automatically.

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: You can use the DepDrop Widget : http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/depdrop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this will help you

_form.php

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'company_id')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
                'data' => ArrayHelper::map(Company::find()->all(),'id','companyname'),
                'language' => 'en',
                'options' => [
                'placeholder' => 'Select a company ...',
                'onchange' => '
                                    $.post( "index.php?r=employee/lists&id='.'"+$(this).val(), function( data ) {
                                      $( "select#admin-employee_email" ).html( data );
                                    }),

                                    $.post( "index.php?r=employee/lists1&id='.'"+$(this).val().split("-")[0], function( data ) {
                                      $( "select#admin-phone" ).html( data );
                                    }),

                                    $.post( "index.php?r=employee/lists1&id='.'"+$(this).val().split("-")[0], function( data ) {
                                      $( "select#admin-age" ).html( data );
                                    }),

                                    $.post( "index.php?r=employee/lists2&id='.'"+$(this).val().split("-")[0], function( data ) {
                                      $( "select#admin-dateofbirth" ).html( data );
                                    });',
                ],
                'pluginOptions' => [
                    'allowClear' => true
                ],
            ]); ?>
```

controller.php

```
public function actionLists($id)
    {
        $countEmployee = Employee::find()
                ->where(['id' => $id])
                ->count();


        $employee= Employee::find()
                ->where(['id' => $id])
                ->all();

        if($countEmployee >= 0)
        {
            foreach($employeeas as $emp)
            {
                echo "<option value='".$emp->id."'>".$emp->email."</option>";

            }
        }
        else{
            echo "<option>-</option>";
        }

    }
```

Do it for all